# Change GarageBand recording directory

Tags: audio, ssd, garageband

When recording audio in GarageBand (open GarageBand, New Project, Voice, then start recording). I would like to record to an external SSD rather than the system disk as I get occasional crashes that seem to be heavy IO related (either to much IO, or perhaps the disk is hitting a thermal shutdown point, I'm not sure). A simple solution seems to be to record the audio to an external SSD and bypass the internal spinning disk. Is there some hidden setting I can change to set the directory/location where GarageBand records audio to by default?

This is on Mac OS X 10.12.1, GarageBand 10.1.4.

Comment: It may help if you provide more details. As a minimum, the version of GarageBand and version of macOS you're running would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a lot about GarageBand - but I move most of ~/Library directories (where most of the User stuff is being kept) by simply linking them to a different place with:

`ln -s /your/source/directory /your/target/directory` in terminal.

for example, **assuming** that GarageBand is saving music to `~/Library/GarageBand/Music` please move the directory first with

`mv ~/Library/Music/GarageBand ~/Library/Music/GarageBand.bak/`

and then try to link a directory in the place of `~/Library/Music/GarageBand` (the `~` resolves to your /Users/username or `$HOME` and is simply a shortcut to your home directory)

`ln -s /Volumes/YourDevice/YourDirectory/GarageBandMusic ~/Library/GarageBand/Music`

**assuming** it is the place where your data is being stored. You could try to create a hard-link without the `-s` flag, but this is not possible for cross-device targets (i.e another hard-drive)

I'm sure you can do this, there are more ways to force macOS to use linked directories.

I don't know about GarageBand - but I keep my Mails, iTunes, Photos, Dropbox etc. on a different drive simply by either using symbolic links or, if necessary by hard-linking them to another directory.

For hard links *workaround* in macOS use https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink it does work very well.

**Keep in mind** that if you `rm -rf` a **symbolic link** directory **you delete link only**.

When you do the same with hard-link on the filesystem then `rm -rf` **follows your link** and deletes the things linked to it!

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Sadly no, I just want the temporary recordings sent to the SSD, not the entire directory and so on.

Comment: You are sure that the temporary recordings kept in the same directory? I wouldnt be so sure. Have you checked the fs activity durning recording? Use `sudo opensnoop` to find out exactly where GarageBand is writing what and then relink that part, if it's using the /private dir-tree on macOS for it - then it would be hard, but still possible. You could give out some more information, you know, it's hard to guess - and I would like to help you to solve it ;-)

Comment: Also check out `default read | grep -i 'garage'` for any clues - like previously stated, it's a matter of finding out what's being written to where and redirecting that operation somewhere else - if this is causing GarageBand to crash, could you put your crashlog here? Review `log stream` for more clues. `log stream --predicate 'sybusystem contains com.whatever.garageband.sub.is' --level=debug` or `log stream --predicate 'processID >insert Garageband pid here<' --level=debug`